# show that below four points are non coplanar

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, analytic-geometry

show that the points P,Q,R and S whose position vectors are p=i+j+3k , q=4i+3j+2k r=5i+2j+7k s=6i+4j+8k are non co planar and find the volume ofthe tetrahedron formed by these four points.

Comment: Once you calculate the volume, you'll know whether the points are coplanar (volume = 0) or not. What have you tried, and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

The volume is:
$$
V=\frac{1}{6}\left|
\begin{array}{cccc}
1& 1& 3& 1\\
4& 3& 2& 1\\
5& 2& 7& 1\\
6& 4& 8& 1\\
\end{array}
\right|
$$